# Экранирование обратного флеша ("\\")

Tags: c#, экранирование

Столкнулся с ситуацией: требуется из строки **"xyz\abc"** убрать  **("\\")** и заменить на  **("\")**.

Другими словами:
**"xyz\abc".Replace("\",..** а вот второй аргумент написать не могу - вариант "\" он не принимает, вариант @"\" - не срабатывает, отладка показывает что это тоже самое: @"\"="\"..

Comment: Эм... Вы хотите символ `\` заметить на тот же самый?

Comment: @chudo116: Наверное, вы имеете в виду `"\"\\\""`?

Comment: Прочтите [эту][1] статью пожалуйста.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h21280bw.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace(@"\\",@"\")
Replace("\\\\","\\")
```

Comment: Zufir, спасибо